# Products have table, flat, or free shipping rates How to write a query to receive all rates

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables that contain the info I need and have created an SQL query that produces the correct results. The problem is that I have some table columns that I want to perform an `if-then` statement on.

For example:

```
Apples: 25:15.00,50:10.00,100:0.00
```

This reads up to 25 apples charge 15.00 shipping, up to 50 charge 10.00 etc..etc..

```
Oranges: 15.00
```

This charges a flat rate of 15.

```
Bananas: 0.00
```

This means free.

So basically I want to be able to perform a `preg_split()` on each and every instance of the table rate and then add all those values together same with the flat rates. And then add both of the table rate and flat rate groups together for a proper shipping quote.

So if I have ordered 50 Apples 1000 Oranges and 75 Bananas, my shipping total would calculate out to be 25.00.

I already have the code I want to perform on each instance of the table rate:

```
$table_cost = preg_split("^[:,]^" , $rate );
$size = sizeof($table_cost);
  for ($i=0, $n=$size; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    if ($order_total <= $table_cost[$i]) {
      $var = $table_cost[$i+1];
    }
  }
```

`$rate` is the variable for the table rates that the query produces
`$order_total` is the varible for the qty, price, or weight of the products. To keep it simple we are going to use `qty` for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You ***really*** need to re-visit your database schema, as your entire question comes as a result of ignoring normalization rules. You have a multi-valued field that you're wanting to run regex on, instead of storing that data as fields that you can relate to.

[Here's an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b1888/1) that demonstrates the case. (Note that I'm going to be using PgSQL because I'm not terribly familiar with MySQL's syntax off-hand, and I didn't want to bother to look it up - but it should be pretty easy to map between the two.) I'm also using an in-database "shopping_cart" table, just so that I can demonstrate the SQL for the solution without hard-coding a bunch of values; there's no reason the solution needs to even store these values in the database to work as demonstrated.

If you need help turning your current data into a normalized structure, there are plenty of [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tools that are designed specifically for these kinds of tasks; Wikipedia has a [decent list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:ETL_tools) of them for you, but I personally prefer to use [Pentaho's Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), an open-source ETL tool that is very powerful and fairly easy to use.

Lastly, I'd recommend spending some time with a decent resource to help you learn relational databases; [Chris Date's book "SQL and Relational Theory"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596523068) is one that I like to have people read, and (if at all possible), go through the [video lecture series](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920002710.do) put out by O'Reilly and Associates.

Comment: Thank you for such an honest response and I'll take a closer look at my code.  Yes standardizing the data before i put it into the table would be the way to go! I just thought it would be easier. lol not true.

Comment: This has made me rethink database operations! Thankyou i'll let you know if it works out by tommorow!

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved with the proper values

@TML

Thankyou so much for enlightening  me on how databases should be written! 
here is the code!

```
$sql = "select distinct srp.p_rate, srp.p_qty, srp.p_id, cb.customers_basket_quantity \n"
. "from `shipping_rates_p` srp\n"
. "join `customers_basket` cb on (cb.customers_basket_quantity <= srp.p_qty and
cb.products_id = srp.p_id)\n"
. "join `products` p on p.products_id = srp.p_id \n"
. "where cb.customers_id=\'3\'\n"
. "group by srp.p_id\n"
```

which returns the proper values that i need!